# appsetting not working in wcfservice web.config file

Tags: wcf, configuration, web-config

Detailed Error Information:
Module     IIS Web Core

Config Error       The configuration section appSetting cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration

my web.config file below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<configuration>
    <appSetting>
        <add key="myserver" value="localhost:12345,localhost:12346"/>
    </appSetting>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `appSettings` instead.